# jQuery history support that works with 1.9+ version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, browser-history

I need to add hash tags to my URLs for popup AJAX editors. So that they can be bookmarked, and support the history back button.

Previously, I've used the [jQuery History](http://balupton.github.com/jquery-history/demo/) plugin from here. It doesn't seem to have been updated in a while, and I get errors about $.browser when using jQuery 1.9. That feature was removed from jQuery.

I'm looking for a replacement that works with jQuery 1.9+

Comment: If you don't have to support IE 7 you can just use the hashchange event. It is supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: @Daff thanks, I'll look into that function. That might be all that I need. I don't care about IE7 (screw them!!!)

Comment: Have you tried using this version of it yet? https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: @KevinB thanks Kevin. I got ti working with just hashchange, but I'll download that version for safe keeping.

Comment: Why was this closed, You asked a valid question!!  use this http://bit.ly/1584GJq

Comment: Finally an explanation of why Balupton's software wasn't working for me. I am on jQuery 1.91. This should not be closed, in fact this information is probably the answer to every question where History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {} ) is not triggering & giving no error.